# How can I make checkboxes visible for all recycler view items without calling notifydatasetchanged?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-glide, notifydatasetchanged

I have been trying to make a photo gallery app and I want to select multiple photos.
The problem in the current implementation is that when I try to longpress to make checkbox visible, the thumbnails are reloading for a fraction of second.
This is because I am calling notifydatasetchanged() after I longpress so that onbindviewholder can load the checkboxes on the screen for every recycler view item, which in turn reloads the thumbnails.
I am using glide to load thumbnails.

Comment: There is `notifyItemChanged()` to propagate changes on a single item

Comment: @Zain notifyItemChanged() will only show checkbox for the item selected. I want all the items present on the screen to update with checkbox without reloading the itemview.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.